# z-index or similar in material design lite

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I'm designing a back-end for a blog-like system, with filters that sieve a list of posts by section, language, etc... The filter is a simple drop down menu, placed at a card's title bar. I want this list in front of everything, of course, but while I've managed to overflow their own card, I can't put this menu in front of the following card. Many options are lost behind the next card.

I've tried many options, but now I'm run out of ideas. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
.menuFilter {
    z-index:1; /* Higher z-index means upper position */
}
.mdl-card {
    overflow: visible; /* menus can leave their own box */
    z-index:0; /* Lower z-index means lower position */
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dv0k3nos/1/

You need to click the menu "FO", at the top right of the first card.

There is some way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will affect anything, but does applying `position: relative` do something?

Comment: I've tried. Nothing.

Comment: Have you try `z-index: -1`;

Comment: yeps, -1, -9999, +1 and +99999. Nothing.

Comment: Make  a jsfiddle to show us a better understanding of you problem

Comment: This might be helpful - [z-index](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/#why-does-it-cause-confusion)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Luis. Sorry for the delay, I'm new here and I didn't expect response so quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/dv0k3nos/1/

Answer (score 1):

> z-index only has an effect if an element is positioned.

**[More here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)**.

A simple example, see if this help you.!

```css
.menuFilter {
    z-index:1; /* Higher z-index means upper position */
    position:relative; /*--Position--*/
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    background:#1266ae;
    color:#fff;
}
.mdl-card {
    z-index:0; /* Lower z-index means lower position */
    position:relative;  /*--Position--*/
    background:#16acff;
    width:100px;
    padding:20px;
    top:-25px;
    left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuFilter">menuFilter</div>
<div class="mdl-card">mdl-card</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I ran into these issues with `overflow` and `z-index` when using mdl menus within mdl cards recently and figured I would post what worked for me since this is one of the top results on Google.

Just need to update `.mdl-card` as follows:

```
.mdl-card {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index:auto;
}
```

[And here is a working version of the jsfiddle you posted.](http://jsfiddle.net/q8qr0aed/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `z-index`, each element that is using it must have `position:absolute`

Comment: I've tried to specify a position for each element. Nothing changes. Well, absolute position crashes the whole design, but doesn't change this unwanted behaviour.